# How to describe this relation

Tags: optimization

The constraint I want to place is $Mx_i-y_i<0$,that is to say when $y_i = 0$ ,then $x_i$ must equal to $0$. However the constraint is only needed when $a>b$ ($a,b$ are both the parameters).

Can I describe the constraint as below?

$$Mx_i-y_i < 0,\ a>b.$$

Comment: do you mean when and only when?

Comment: thank you for your responding,i mean only when.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are parameters, then you can control which constraints you give to the solver. If $a>b$ add the following constraint:
$$
x_i\le My_i
$$
(If $x_i$ is binary, $M:=1$ is suitable)

If not, do not add the constraint. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Is the $M$ misplaced?

Comment: $M$ is not misplaced: if $y_i=0$, $x_i\le0$. If $y_i=1$, $x_1\le M$ (the constraint is inactive).

Comment: sorry for confusing, in the constraint,Xi are binary variables.

Comment: No problem, in this case set $M$ to $1$.

Comment: thank you very much!but,i still want to know how to describe this relation in an optimization model using mathematical symbols

Comment: may i add a＞b behind the constraint?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. This is an optimization model using symbols. You can add "if a>b" after the constraint, sure.